# How to get right to "Java" in control panel from cmd line in win7?

Tags: java, cmd, controlpanel

- win +r
- "control"

puts me right into control panel, and into search - I can type 'JAVA', still fast,but is there way to jump right into "java" from cmdline?

I just wanna add bit more efficiency to it.

Comment: What do you want to do after you get to the java control panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`control "C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin\javacpl.cpl"`

Replace path with your Java installation.

Alternatively, you can also use `javaws -viewer`.

Note that you might need an elevated command prompt (Run as Administrator) instead of "regular" one.